# Query a list of records with ActiveRecord where foreign keys of each item are present in a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have four models - User, Agency, Listing and Inquiry.

A User `has_one` Agency, an Agency `has_many` Listings, and a Listing `has_many` Inquiries.

I have a query where I get a `:user_id`, so I can get its Agency and the collection of Listings.

I need the Inquiries that belong to a certain Listing.

My approach is the following, obviously I'm looking for a replacement for `all`. I'd like to make a query where I can list all the inquiries where `:listing_id` is the id of one of the listings in `@listings`.

```
  def index
    @agency = User.find(params[:user_id]).agency
    @listings = @agency.listings

    @inquiries = Inquiry
      .all

    render json: @inquiries
  end
```

I tried combining various `select`, `includes`, `where`, etc. methods but couldn't come up with a working solution.

Thank you for your help, much appreciated!

Comment: Can you show some of the things you tried? It will help prevent duplicate efforts.

Answer (score 3):

We can use mutiple joins in a single query to reach till the resulted association.

```
def index
  @inquiries = Inquiry.joins(listing: { agency: :user }).where(users: { id: params[:user_id] })

 render json: @inquiries
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you are using something like RuboCop it will probably warn you that you usually only pass one, possibly two instance variables in a method like this. Not that I haven't done it, it's just not considers optimal Rails. That said:

One way might be this:

```
def index
  @agency = User.find(params[:user_id]).agency
  @listings = @agency.listings

  @inquiries = Inquiry.where(listing_id: @listings.pluck(:id))

 render json: @inquiries
end
```

You can pass an array of things to match with `where`. `pluck` gives you an array of what ever columns you pass to it.

Comment: If I need data from multiple tables for an instance variable to pass to the view I would normally use a join of some sort.

Comment: Be aware that this solution has poor performance (3 queries to the db). Prefer to use "join" solution to make a single query.

Comment: Be aware that's why I said "not optimal Rails" and advised using a join in the first comment. I did want to show that it was possible to replace "all" with something more specific.  I wanted to add a join answer but was unsure of the exact syntax for his use as I've gotten rusty at it.

Comment: It's worth mentioning the keyword "join" and to explain why it is not optimized. That's the purpose of my comment :-)